# How do I resolve a Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.AmbientDataException: SQL exception?

Tags: content-delivery, ambient-data-framework

I have been checking the configurations for content delivery but keep getting this error when I am loading the site. It appears to be telling me it is related to a SQL error but I double checked the web.config and xmls files in config folders and they seem to be straight.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this one?

> [AmbientDataException: SQL exception]
>     Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +514
>     Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1243
>     Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +915
>     Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine(AmbientDataConfig ambientDataConfig) +159
>     Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.InitializeAmbientFramework() +226
>     Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +90
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +575
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
>     System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): SQL exception]
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11702064
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4870277

Comment: Try setting the application pool to enable 32 bit and also .net 4.0.

Comment: @fsnova did you ever come to a solution for your issue, or is this question still open? Perhaps you can provide an update (either by editing the question and supplying more information or posting an answer with the solution and accepting that)?

Answer (score 4):

90% of the time my SQL Errors are because I forgot to drop the 3rd party jar "**sqljdbc4.jar**" into my application /bin/lib directory, i'd first confirm you have this.

Failing that you can configure content delivery logging via your logback.xml file, this should give you a lot more information as what's going on in your app and the cause of the failure.

If you still can't solve it after confirming the jar and consulting the logs, perhaps update your question with your log file?

Comment: I have double checked the sqljdbc4.jar was in bin/lib folder. I also downloaded the updated version sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu to ensure the file is up to date and not corrupted.

Comment: I checked the logs in C:\tridion\log and only sync_audiencemanager log was updated. There is an error still related to SQLException.

Comment: 2013-05-03 16:45:17,109 ERROR Contact - Unable to instantiate contact object
java.sql.SQLException: No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile
 at com.tridion.marketingsolution.profile.ExtendedDetails.loadExtendedDetailsTemplate(ExtendedDetails.java:51) ~[oe_profile.jar:na]

Answer (score 2):

Generally this error comes because of following few reasons:

1. SQLJDBC4.jar is missing or corrupted
2. The JRE Version is between - 1.6.0.25 to 1.6.0.30 - Ensure you JRE version does not lie among any of these versions - This is a known issue with Third Party API
3. You are checking for configs, jar files etc. in a particular Directory but the home directory that is getting loaded is different - Check your event log and ensure that it is getting loaded from the expected directory